# ASP.NET PreInit() and IsPostBack property

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

What does PreInit() do   by   checking  IsPostBack  property?

Genererally while explaining PreInit()  lot webpages  say   it   checks IsPostBack  property.
But   they  don't tell   what will PreInit do if IsPostBack is true or IsPostBack is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx ) that you can use the value of IsPostBack to determine if it's a postback or not.  If it is a postback the values of the controls on the page will not be set yet.

Answer (score 0):

If page is posted, role of preinit to load the data existed on page before post.